# ReactJS: Hiding a text produces an error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, react-component

I just cant hide my text (Header) using a button in a class form. I try this code below:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    showHeader: true,
  }
}
```

And I render the state above using setState:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.showHeader && <Header /> }
      <button onClick={ this.setState({showHeader: false})} >Hide</button>
    </div>
```

I know this is a stupid question but I cant help myself because Im a totally beginner. But I did this right using function and I just want try to convert it using a class. This is what I did using function:

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
const hideHeader = () => {
  setShow(!show)
}
```

And return this:

```
 return (
    <div>
      {show && <Header />}
      <button onClick={hideHeader}>Hide Header</button>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're calling `setState()` in your render function. That's going to cause problems because `setState` causes your `render` method to be called, and if your render method calls `setState` directly, you get caught in a loop.

What you need to do is call it in an event handler instead:

```
// bad
onClick={this.setState({showHeader: false})}
// good
onClick={() => this.setState({showHeader: false})}
```

So your button should look like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({showHeader: false})} >Hide</button>
```

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render):

> The `render()` function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So if I want to modify a state, I should use function and a setState right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You want to make sure that your `setState()` call is in a function, rather than directly called within render.